# visual studio 2012 hides error locations

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I recently installed Visual Studio 2012 at work and found it doesn't reliably show me the location of my errors in the code.

This is what I see in VS 2012:

[image: 2012 error list with no file locations]

This is the exact same project in VS 2010:

[image: 2010 error list with file locations]

If I double click on a row it only highlights the line and does not go to the location in a file:

[image]

If I look at the output I can see this:

[image]

And if I double click on **that** I get directed to a meta file:

[image]

The meta file that comes up (Workflow.Targets) does not surface in the Solution Explorer. When I click "Locate in Solution Explorer" it highlights the top file in the Solution Explorer (which happens to be a directory).

Although this solution does use WF, I don't think it's a Windows Work Flow problem because (as you can see from the 2010 error screen) the origin is a C# file (CommunicationModule.cs).

Right now I am stuck with VS 2010 or using global find to hunt them down :(

**EDIT**:

I got through this round of errors using 2010. From that point on 2012 has cooperated.

Also -at the risk of getting beat up on the internet- I like the metro look and feel of 2012!

Comment: When you double-click an entry in the Error list, nothing happens?  After you double-click, where is the current line in the Output window and what does *it* look like?

Comment: @PeterRitchie : It does nothing. If I view the output and double-click on that it takes me to a meta file.